# SED / AWK multi-file replacement?

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I've been trying to figure out a command that will search through 13+ files and replace
all matches and variances of forms data and replace them with form data enhancements.

The trick is that there could be [whitespace] - or _ as a separator that I would like
to preserve. I'm running form command line so I believe I could run this script multiple
times and just point it at the file, or if there's a way to capture all files in a directory
(even including directory names) it might just be easier.

I believe its something to the tune of

> sed "s/forms_data/form-data-enhancements/g ; s/forms-data/form-data-enhancements/g ; s/forms data/form data enhancements/g" oldfile > newfile

nut I'm not sure.....

variances might be

> forms-data
>
> forms_data
>
> forms data

etcetra. Would someone mind sharing a bit of sed awk wisdom? The best I can find is something called an arrary replace but was unable to get any information on how to use it.

Thanks greatly.

Comment: This is too general to be actionable. You'll get better responses if you include actual (but short) sample input and required output. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you -

```
sed -i 's/\<forms[ -_]data\>/form data enhancements/g' /path/to/files*
```

`-i` will do in-file substitution. So first pick a file and run the command without the `-i` option. If everything looks ok then you can go ahead and use the `-i`.

#### Update:

If you would like to retain the separators then you can do something like this -

```
sed -i 's/\<forms\([ -_]\)data\>/form\1data\1enhancements/' /path/to/files*
```

Comment: Jaypal wouldn't I need a way to carry over the [ -_] to include in form data enhancements though?

Comment: Or use `-i.bak` option to keep a backup file with .bak extension if something goes wrong.

Comment: As per your question, you wanted to `replace all matches and variances of forms data and replace them with form data enhancements`. [ -_] is a character class which will match all variances. Do you wish to retain the word separator?

Comment: I do, I want to be sure to carry them over since this is for a drupal program, they are very sensitive about separators.

Comment: sed -i -e 's/\<forms[ -_]/{h;}data\>/form{b;}data{b;}enhancements/g' /path/to/files* or something, right?

Comment: @ehime I have added an alternate solution that might help.

Comment: edited yours to include an escape for the mdash, it was breaking stuff ;)